# How do I get "id" from fxml and you use it to printiline?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have fxml file called :"MainScene"

```
.....
<Label fx:id="statusLabel" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Status: 200" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
....
```

I need to printline "statuslabel". My question is how do I get it ? I have "MainSceneTest":

```
package wrapper.sk.machine.controller;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

class MainSceneTest {

    @DisplayName("should create status message from status code")
    System.println(statusLabel);    // this is probably wrong or it is one of the last step

    @Test
    void shouldCreateStatusLabelFromStatusCode() {
        fail();
    }

}
```

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: First make sure to create Java code that actually compiles

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I need to fill it , but I dont know how to get "statusLabel " from fxml

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: What actually do you want to print?  The characters "statusLabel", or the text in the label "Status: 200"?  And why from a test case and not an app?  If an app and you want to print the text, then have `@FXML Label statusLabel;` in your controller, and call `statusLabel.getText()`.  If a test case look into TestFX library,  If you don't know what @FXML and a controller is, study an FXML tutorial.

Comment: @jewelsea I want print text in the label "Status: 200"

Comment: In a unit test case or during application execution?  What is your purpose?  Please provide some context for the question to help answer it better.

Comment: @jewelsea I need to write code into "MainSceneTest" which returns id="statuslabel" aka "Status:200". So I was thinking about loading fxml file, and using"id" from this fxml for printing

Comment: Given that you seem to be writing unit tests for JavaFX applications, you could use [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/wiki/Getting-Started). Have an application load your FXML, and in your test write something like `verifyThat("#statusLabel", hasText("Status: 200"));`.  I have not used TestFX, so will refer you to the documentation for details if that is something you wish to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

the right tool for "searching for values in XML" is, of course, [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).
XPath is a path-oriented query language that works on XML documents.  at runtime, XPath works similar to regular expression: it compiles an expression and finds matches in an XML document.

This is how to load a String into an XML document:

```
static Document fromString(String xmlString) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
}
```

in your case, the attribute name contains namespace (the part on the left side of the colon) and that makes the path expr a little more complicated then just searching for an xml attribute

```
String expression = "/Label/@*[name()='fx:id']";
```

This is how to search for an XPath expr in an XML document:

```
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Node node = (Node)xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

and here is the complete solution

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Xpath {

    static final String xmlString = """
        <Label fx:id="statusLabel" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Status: 200" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets left="10.0" />
            </GridPane.margin>
            <font>
                <Font size="20.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>            
    """;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document xmlDocument = fromString(xmlString);
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression = "/Label/@*[name()='fx:id']";
            Node node = (Node)xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static Document fromString(String xmlString) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a good general answer for extracting info from FXML, I have a feeling it is not what the asker is really wanting.  Likely what may be wanted is to get a reference to a Label type loaded by the FXML loader ([using @FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm)) and call the getText method on it to find out what text it is set to, perhaps in a test case of some kind, but the asker can clarify if that is the case.